# WSO2 ESB - How to send response to Intermediate sequence from service provider?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

i  was going through a  video about ["Webinar - ESB - An answer to Enterprise Service Integration"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbnEw_s8vXo) by  WSO2  ESB . i have a doubt regarding the video .

it is said in the video that , always  in sequence will receive the request and out  sequence will  return the response  from the service provider .  An ESb  can have multiple  intermediate sequence  and we can, set to which intermediate sequence service provider has to send  the response .

How is it possible when we do not have any control over the service provider ? are we using some queue in between ESB and service provider to accomplish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a sequence, when you send a request to a service, you can choose the response-handling sequence (service chaining) :

```
<send receive="personInfoSeq">
    <endpoint key="PersonInfoEpr"/>
</send>
```

When the ESB sends the request, a callback is instanciated (a dedicated thread) which will wait for the reply and then execute the 'receive' sequence configured in the 'send' mediator

Inside a sequence, when you are working with a response message, you can change it to a request message (`<property name="RESPONSE" value="false"/>`) and send it to another service

Inside a "in" sequence (when you are working with a request message), you can generate a response, sample :

```
<inSequence>
    <header name="To" action="remove"/>
    <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
    <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
    <payloadFactory>
        <format>
            <ns:getQuoteResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.samples">
                <ns:return xmlns:ax21="http://services.samples/xsd">
                    <ax21:change>4.212070096051944</ax21:change>
                    <ax21:earnings>-9.567415587431361</ax21:earnings>
                    <ax21:high>-148.1740146577308</ax21:high>
                    <ax21:symbol>IBM</ax21:symbol>
                </ns:return>
            </ns:getQuoteResponse>
        </format>
    </payloadFactory>
    <send/>
</inSequence>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ..i understood that,  we can configure WSO2 ESB and make  response-handling sequence to receive the response . However ,  when a client calls a service , service will always reply  to callee . but here we are choosing some different response-handling sequence to receive the reply . How this is handled inside the WSO2 ESB ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure to understand your question. Perhaps this addon will help you : When the ESB sends the request, a callback is instanciated (a dedicated thread) which will wait for the reply and then execute the 'receive' sequence configured in the 'send' mediator

Comment: Got it , technically i wanted to understand how 'recieve' sequence  is being called .  thanks a lot got my answer .

Comment: I've updated my answer, have a look and if OK, don't forget to accept it.